# WCF service wasn't generated the web-config configurations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, console-application

I have a simple WCF service and i would try to add a service reference for my console application it has worked fine and automatically generate the web-config configurations.

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:50765/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="MyFirstService.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

At the same service i try to add a service reference for my MVC project. Service reference added successfully but it wasn't generated the  web-config configurations.
How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Is it giving the error while adding the reference? laso describe the error you facing while calling the service in MVC project ?

Comment: i din't got any errors

Comment: Are you able to create proxy client in your MVC application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be some bug/glitch in Visual Studio. You could always use the [`svcutil.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) tool manually on the command line and it will generate all the necessary stuff:

```
svcutil.exe http://example.com/yourservicemetadata
```

Comment: can you explain more about svcutil.exe

Comment: What further explanation do you need? You fire up a Visual Studio Command Prompt window and type `svcutil.exe http://address_of_your_wcf_service` and it will generate a `.cs` file containing the client proxy classes and an `App.config` file with the necessary sections you need to add to your configuration file.

Comment: Excellent answer. Could you improve it with an MSDN link on how to use the .cs generated?